# Get the currently highlighted text in a OneNote Document

Tags: office-js, onenote-api

When building a word add in I can use

```
var selectedRange = context.document.getSelection();
```

To get the currently selected text, is this possible with Onenote addins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can do this through the `getSelectedDataAsync` method of the Common Office JavaScript API. For details about using this API in OneNote, see [accessing-the-common-api-through-the-document-object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/onenote/onenote-add-ins-programming-overview#accessing-the-common-api-through-the-document-object)